# Обращение к элементу массива jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Получаю такой объект возвращаемый виджетом:

[image: объект]

Мне нужно обратиться к определенным элементам вложенного внутрь массива, в частности `adress->place`.

Знаю что в jQuery можно перебирать массивы как и объекты через `.each`, но мне не надо перебирать его весь, мне надо обратиться к конкретному элементу.

Как например в PHP:

```
$arr['item']['subitem'];
```

Как можно это сделать в jQuery?

На learn.javascript был, там нашел только информацию о переборе объектов и массивов, то есть тот же `.each`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То что описано у Вас в вопросе это обычное получение значение ключа у объекта:

```js
const object = {
  address: {
    country: "Russia",
    city: "Moscow"
  },
  id: 1
}

console.log(object.address.city)
// Moscow

console.log(object["address"]["city"])
// Moscow
```

Если у Вас массив объектов, то:

```js
const array = [
  {
    address: {
      country: "Russia",
      city: "Moscow"
    },
    id: 1
  },
  {
    address: {
      country: "Russia",
      city: "Saint-Petersburg"
    },
    id: 2
  }
]

console.log(array[0].address.city)
// Moscow

console.log(array[0]["address"]["city"])
// Moscow
```

*Нет разницы JS или jQuery, все делается одинаково в обоих случаях.*

Answer (score 3):

Обращение к полям объекта производится через точку `item.adress.place` либо через скобочную нотацию  `item['address']['place']`